# what frequencies is this antenna cut for?

Tags: antenna-construction, vertical-antenna

[image]I just bought a magnet-mount whip antenna at a garage sale. It has no brand markings anywhere on it. it is 32" long overall but is broken up into three segments by what appear to be two small potted loading coils. The shortest segment is at the bottom and measures 4 1/2" from the top of the base to the center of the first coil. the next segment measures 9 1/2" between the centers of the coils and the topmost segment measures 18" from the center of the second coil to the tip of the whip. the coils are equipped with setscrews for clamping onto the whip segments and the coax connector looks like a BNC.

Can anyone tell me what frequencies this antenna was intended for?

Comment: I think a simple picture would ... illustrate this rather well.

Comment: Without access to those potted "loading coils", I doubt this can be answered. Please post a photo.

Comment: Do you have an antenna analyzer?

Comment: I know who to borrow one from!!!

Comment: That would be the best way to answer your question.

Comment: Agree, and thanks for the advice. I suspect it is a 144/220/440 tribander...